# Is there a way I can make my textarea grow to match the size of my text?

Tags: jquery

I have a text area that has a width of 100. Sometimes this is has a few words of text and other times a few hundred. Is there some way that I could make the height adjust to the amount of text using jQuery or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [TextAreaExpander](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html) plugin.

Others include

- [Autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize)
- [Elastic](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this as someone the text-area size increases

```
  <textarea style='overflow-y:hidden;' onkeyup='this.rows = (this.value.split("\n").length||1);'>
    </textarea>
```

here are more approaches
http://perplexed.co.uk/596_expanding_textarea_as_you_type.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS [`resize`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize) property:

```
textarea { 
   resize: both; 
   width: 100px;
   min-height:200px; 
   max-height:300px; 
}
```